# How can I use Edge Creasing with OpenSubdiv?

Tags: modeling, edges, subdivision-surface

I see that OpenSubdiv has been integrated but could not find any material about using it for utilizing its edge creasing capability to create harder edges in subd-modeling instead of using support loops. Of course I fiddled around but could get no result, just strange shading as if it's not working properly.
It seems to makes subd and hard edges so much easier as shown here for example in 3ds Max (video by Arrimus 3D)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFckVSyvVy4

Answer (score 1):

OpenSubdiv has not been completely implemented into Blender. It is currently only used for viewport playback speed for animators.

[Official Document about it's implementation](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/OpenSubdiv)

Limitations
There are number of limitations which are not resolvable with the current OpenSubdiv release and current OpenGL profile of Blender itself:

- Smooth normals aren't currently correct. This goes into limitations of GLSL level we can currently use in Blender and what OpenSubdiv can provide us. It's being worked on though with high priority.
- No OSX support, Historically Blender is using rather old OpenGL API and OpenSubdiv is using OpenGL 4. This makes it impossible to make Blender working with OpenSubdiv on OSX due to policy from Apple which forces everyone to drop older OpenGL code if newer API is used in application.
- No UV maps support in viewport. This limitation is caused by OpenSubdiv which currently doesn't have nice support of UV mapping evaluation on GPU and has no way to calculate UVs on CPU as well.
- No generated coordinates support. Generated coordinates in blender requires calculation of undeformed mesh on CPU which makes it rather really complicated to use OpenSubdiv in such configuration because all it's data is on GPU.
- Tools which requires having mesh on CPU (for example snap tools) will fail for OpenSubdiv mesh. This also includes areas like geometry primitive counter in the Info header.
- Currently shading is limited to a single material only. This is easy to resolve from Blender side and will happen sooner than later.
- Loose edges and vertices are not supported.
- Auto split is not working yet
- Loop normals are not supported yet as well